# inf ServiceBinary - quote path with spaces

Tags: service, driver, inf

I have a .inf file for installing a service.
The path of the installation contains spaces.
I want to quote them, for avoiding [security issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2014/11/14/it-rather-involved-being-on-the-other-side-of-this-airtight-hatchway-unquoted-service-paths/).

Currently, the inf has these lines:

```
ServiceBinary  = %10%\path\with sub folder that contains spaces\myservice.exe
```

and

```
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 10,path\with sub folder that contains spaces
```

So in order to the service appear with quotes here:
*HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\myservice\ImagePath*

I have changed `ServiceBinary`, as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-services-registry-tree).

I have tried all of these but with no success:

```
ServiceBinary  = "%10%\path\with sub folder that contains spaces\myservice.exe"
ServiceBinary  = ""%10%\path\with sub folder that contains spaces\myservice.exe""
ServiceBinary  = %10%""\path\with sub folder that contains spaces\myservice.exe""
```

Do you know what should I change in my .inf file, so the service's exe path will be quoted in the registry (and service's Path to Executable property as well)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer...

```
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 10,""path\with sub folder that contains spaces""
```

and

```
ServiceBinary  = """%10%\path\with sub folder that contains spaces\myservice.exe"""
```

Pay attention to the three(!) quotation  marks for `ServiceBinary`.

You can see [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-strings-section) for more info.